# How to share WordPress post to Instagram without plugin

Tags: wordpress, instagram

I want to share the article on social media such as Twitter, LinkedIn, Facebook, and Instagram without using plugins. I find out three URL's for Twitter, LinkedIn, and Facebook as

```
<?php
http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php the_title();
?>;&amp;url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&via=<?php the_author_meta(
'twitter' ); ?>

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink());?>

https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;title=<?php the_title(); ?>.
```

But I didn't found for Instagram. can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Have you found any solutions, Please share if you found .